# Smartcard use with GPG on CentOS 8 Stream

Tags: centos, gpg, yubikey, smartcard

I cannot get my smartcard (Yubikey 5 Nano, setup with CCID and keys installed on a Windows system) to work on my CentOS 8 Stream machine. I would like to sign Github commits with it. It's a buildroot project where files from which are "illegal" in the Windows system.

`gpg --card-status` returns `gpg: selecting card failed: No such device`

`gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such device`

Scdaemon log shows `scdaemon[3555] pcsc_connect failed: sharing violation (0x8010000b)`

Also shows my Yubikey as a 4 for some reason `detected reader 'Yubico Yubikey 4 OTP+U2F+CCID 00 00'`

I've done a lot of research and tried many things to no avail.

Here are versions of installed software:

- gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.20
- libgcrypt 1.8.5
- scdaemon (GnuPG) 2.2.20
- libksba 1.3.5
- pcsc-lite.x86_64 1.8.23-4.1.el8
- pcsc-lite-ccid.x86_64 1.4.29-5.1.el8
- pcsc-lite-libs.x86_64 1.8.23-4.1.el8
- pcsc-perl.x86_64 1.4.14-12.el8
- pcsc-tools.x86_64 1.5.3-3.el8
- pcsc-cyberjack.x86_64 3.99.5final.SP14-1.el8
- pcsc-cyberjack-cjflash.x86_64 3.99.5final.SP14-1.el8
- pcsc-cyberjack-examples.noarch 3.99.5final.SP14-1.el8
- pcsc-lite-doc.noarch 1.8.23-4.1.el8
- pcsc-lite-libs.i686 1.8.23-4.1.el8
- pcsc-tools-gscriptor.x86_64 1.5.3-3.el8
- pinentry-curses (pinentry) 1.1.0

I have followed several guides

https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide

https://gist.github.com/ageis/14adc308087859e199912b4c79c4aaa4

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770378/failure-to-use-udev-rule-to-change-smart-card-device-ownership-in-xen-qubesos-vm

I've setup udev rules for the Yubikey and tried to get the gnome-keyring to not start like some guides say since it's a known issue that the keyring will hold the smartcard up from being used by gpg. I think this is the issue but I cannot rectify it. Has anyone had any luck with getting this to work? Especially on CentOS 8 Stream?

Thanks in advanced. If any other info is needed please don't hesitate to ask. I am not a Linux novice but I am not a Linux expert by any stretch of the imagination. Any help at all is welcome.

~ejc

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. The opensc package was hanging up the smartcard.

Do a `sudo yum remove opensc` and GPG can access the smartcard.

Also followed these links to sign Github commits with GPG

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key

https://gist.github.com/xavierfoucrier/c156027fcc6ae23bcee1204199f177da

I really hope this helps someone else down the line.